# Regular Pentagonal Dodecahedron measurement help please

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a regular pentagonal dodecahedron and the diameter of the spherical surface passing through all 20 identical vertices is 5 inches, what would the length of one pentagon side edge be in inches?

How about if the spherical surface diameter is 6 inches as well? thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I would like to but I am not skilled in math lol I tried to read through the answer already here using a radius but I got lost quickly lol

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Dimensions

Comment: would the edge length on a 5" D be 1.784" and on a 6" D be 2.141?

Comment: You got it yourself. Your values are correct.